# How can I get a list of all blocks proposed by a validator?

Tags: staking, validators, beacon-chain, api

I would like to get all blocks proposed by a given validator. It looks like this functionality is not available in the standard Beaconchain API. Is there any other API available, probably by a a third party, that can provide this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this with the website https://beaconcha.in/

For instance you can get the list of blocks proposed by the validator 255334 with the link https://beaconcha.in/validator/255334#blocks.

Comment: I was looking for an API and was not aware that beaconcha.in also provides one :) I'm going to use this endpoint: https://beaconcha.in/api/v1/docs/index.html#/Validator/get_api_v1_validator__indexOrPubkey__proposals